# Unable to enter webkitRelativePath data into textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Sapphion/HcD9c/light/ where I've used a div section to display the list of file names and folder that are got by browsing folders in **Google Chrome**

**WORKS:**

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple webkitdirectory />
<div id="output"></div>
```

**DOES NOT WORK:**

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple webkitdirectory />
<div id="output"></div>
 <textarea id="output" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>
```

I've modified it to http://jsfiddle.net/HcD9c/57/ in which I enter the data into a textarea. But this doesnt seem to happen. **ONLY** the first element is entered into the textbox.

Thanks for your help.

John

Comment: Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: answered your question below. check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use innerHTML for adding value for textarea. You need to use value property. Use your javascript like below.

```
 var input = document.getElementById('files');
 var output = document.getElementById('output');
 var targ = event.target || event.srcElement;

 input.onchange = function(e) {
 var files = e.target.files; // FileList
 for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; ++i){
    console.debug(files[i].webkitRelativePath);
    output.value += targ.textContent || targ.innerText + files[i].webkitRelativePath+"\n";  
}
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HcD9c/59/)